# How to find number ranges (with text input) in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

In column A, I have some numbers, formatted as text due to leading zeros:

```
+------+
|  A   |
+------+
| 0001 |
| 0002 |
| 0003 |
| 0012 |
| 0013 |
| 0015 |
| 0017 |
| 0019 |
| 0020 |
+------+
```

Using column A as input, I want to populate two other columns, B and C, like this:

```
+------+------+
|  B   |  C   |
+------+------+
| 0001 | 0003 |
| 0012 | 0013 |
| 0015 |      |
| 0017 |      |
| 0019 | 0020 |
+------+------+
```

I basically want the beginning and end of each number range.

Numbers not included in column A should be omitted from the ranges in column B and C.

How can this be accomplished in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Sub dural()
  Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long, v As Long
  Dim vOld As Long
  N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
  K = 1

  For i = 1 To N
    v = CLng(Cells(i, 1).Value)
    If i = 1 Then
      Cells(1, "B").Value = v
      vOld = v
    Else
      If v = vOld + 1 Then
      Else
        Cells(K, "C").Value = vOld
        K = K + 1
        Cells(K, "B") = v
      End If
      vOld = v
    End If
  Next i

  For i = 1 To K
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = Cells(i, "C").Value Then Cells(i, "C").Value = ""
    If Cells(i, "B").Value = 0 Then Cells(i, "B").Value = ""
  Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks - It's working great. Do you know how I can make it output text format, so that the leading zeros are kept in the ranges? These are zip codes, so the leading zeros are necessary.

Comment: @Leif  You can use a Custom number format of **0000** to keep the leading zeros.